# How to do inference on a tensor2tensor model in python (without the decoding binary and TensorFlow Serving)

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensor2tensor

I am a bit confused on how to do inference on a tensor2tensor model without using the decoding binaries and TensorFlow Serving. The following two code examples seems to be the closest thing to it but I get a "Cannot convert a symbolic Tensor" error.

model output gives me this before it goes through the decoder and throws the error:

```
<tf.Tensor 'transformer/strided_slice:0' shape=(?, ?) dtype=int32>
```

https://gist.github.com/alexwolf22/7b24636c99a6f56da13c27a1ce573b8a#file-using_t2t_models-py
https://gist.github.com/alexwolf22/e0ae60d8908c2772f2d3aedacf0ea618#file-decode_t2t_funcs-py

**What might I be doing wrong? Is there a better example on how to do inference in tensor2tensor with just code?** I have gone through decoding.py in the tensor2tensor repo as well but still no luck. Here was the blog that I was following along with my inference code.

https://medium.com/data-from-the-trenches/training-cutting-edge-neural-networks-with-tensor2tensor-and-10-lines-of-code-10973c030b8

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensor2tensor.utils.trainer_lib import create_hparams, registry
from tensor2tensor import problems
from tensor2tensor.layers import common_hparams
from tensor2tensor.models.transformer import Transformer

def encode(input_txt, encoders):
    """List of Strings to features dict, ready for inference"""
    encoded_inputs = [encoders["inputs"].encode(x) + [1] for x in input_txt]

    # pad each input so is they are the same length
    biggest_seq = len(max(encoded_inputs, key=len))
    for i, text_input in enumerate(encoded_inputs):
        encoded_inputs[i] = text_input + [0 for x in range(biggest_seq - len(text_input))]

    # Format Input Data For Model
    batched_inputs = tf.reshape(encoded_inputs, [len(encoded_inputs), -1, 1])
    return {"inputs": batched_inputs}


def decode(integers, encoders):
    """Decode list of ints to list of strings""" 

    # Turn to list to remove EOF mark
    to_decode = list(np.squeeze(integers))
    if isinstance(to_decode[0], np.ndarray):
        to_decode = map(lambda x: list(np.squeeze(x)), to_decode)
    else:
        to_decode = [to_decode]

    # remove <EOF> Tag before decoding
    to_decode = map(lambda x: x[:x.index(1)], filter(lambda x: 1 in x, to_decode))

    # Decode and return Translated text
    return [encoders["inputs"].decode(np.squeeze(x)) for x in to_decode]

INPUT_TEXT_TO_TRANSLATE = 'Translate this sentence into French'

# Set Tensor2Tensor Arguments
MODEL_DIR_PATH = 'data'
MODEL = 'transformer'
HPARAMS = 'transformer_base'
T2T_PROBLEM = 'translate_enfr_wmt_small8k_rev'

hparams = create_hparams(HPARAMS, data_dir=MODEL_DIR_PATH, problem_name=T2T_PROBLEM)

# Make any changes to default Hparams for model architechture used during training
hparams.batch_size = 1024
hparams.hidden_size = 7*80
hparams.filter_size = 7*80*4
hparams.num_heads = 8

# Load model into Memory
T2T_MODEL = registry.model(MODEL)(hparams, tf.estimator.ModeKeys.PREDICT)

# Init T2T Token Encoder/ Decoders
DATA_ENCODERS = problems.problem(T2T_PROBLEM).feature_encoders(MODEL_DIR_PATH)

### START USING MODELS
encoded_inputs= encode(INPUT_TEXT_TO_TRANSLATE, DATA_ENCODERS)
model_output = T2T_MODEL.infer(encoded_inputs, beam_size=2)["outputs"]
translated_text_in_french =  decode(model_output, DATA_ENCODERS)

print(translated_text_in_french)
```

Answer (score 0):

hparams.batch_size = 1024

you are predicting in batch mode.
You can update your decode method.

```
# Setup helper functions for encoding and decoding
def encode(input_str, output_str=None):
    """Input str to features dict, ready for inference"""
    inputs = encoders["inputs"].encode(input_str) + [1]  # add EOS id
    batch_inputs = tf.reshape(inputs, [1, -1, 1])  # Make it 3D.
    return {"inputs": batch_inputs}

def decode(integers):
    """List of ints to str"""
    integers = list(np.squeeze(integers))
    if 1 in integers:
      integers = integers[:integers.index(1)]
    return encoders["inputs"].decode(np.squeeze(integers))
```

Please follow the example in the below url.

https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/tensor2tensor/blob/master/tensor2tensor/notebooks/hello_t2t.ipynb#scrollTo=EB4MP7_y_SuQ